# Bot Framework SDK4 C# - send proactive message to a user in Teams / REST response timeout

Tags: botframework

Based on a GitHub sample, I created a dialog bot in Teams that collects information from a user and sends that to a Flow (Microsoft Flow/Power Automate) with a HTTP POST call.

After that the Bot waits for a response and sends it back to the user. This generally would be sufficient if the timeout for the call wasn't limited to 2 minutes - sometimes it takes longer to get the complete actions in Flow and get the response.

My question is how I could accomplish the same without getting the timeout. REST seemed the easiest as I'm not a programmer..

I checked the GitHub sample for proactive messaging (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages), and that worked in the Emulator when I enter *http://localhost:3978/api/notify*, but I have no idea how to use it published to Azure. What would be the endpoint and how I could pass the message text?

Thanks

Comment: So you just want to know the endpoint of proactive-messages after you published your bot to Azure and how to use /notify function to send text messages ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like to know :)

Comment: Hi @xmihu , Has your issue been solved or any assistance needed ? If my answer is helpful , pls kindly mark it as an answer to that it could help others who has similar questions and it will be an award for me : )  Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do some code modify if you want to send an message based on [proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) demo .

You can refer to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069530/get-proactive-message-from-json/58072500#58072500) which will meet your requirement.
After you modify the `NotifyController.cs` file , you can use send messages to a specific user with steps below :

1. Connect to your bot get current user ID : 
   [image]
2. Send message to this user by rest client tool or post man :
   [image]

Result :
[image]

If you publish your bot to Azure , lets assume your Azure App service host is :`https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net` , then your bot message endpoint will be :`https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/messages` and your /notify function endpoint will be : `https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/notify` . In brief , just use your Azure App service endpoint to replace `http://localhost:3978` will be fine .

Hope it helps . If there is anything unclear pls feel free to let me know .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Stanley Gong
I will try to test it using your solution tomorrow, but I can already see it will  help much.

Comment: Hi @StanleyGong I added the notify controller to my chatbot. When I send request from Postman, the status is 500 Internal Server Error. Do you have any idea about that? This is the 'System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[System.String,Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ConversationReference]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Controllers.NotifyController'' error.

Comment: @Stanley Gong Should we need to provide any authorization token when calling the https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/notify api.

Comment: @Stanley, I am having a similar issue. I hosted the bot on Azure and had it installed on Microsoft Teams, now I don't know how to call the notify endpoint on Teams to invoke the proactive message.

Comment: @Bloggrammer,I am sorry, I am not so familiar with teams bot :(